# How to mark last row in DataGridView in case of vertical scroll bar?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have try `MyDataGridView.Rows[index].Selected = true;` but this marked all the rows.

What i want is in case of vertical scroll bar i want to see the last row without do it manually

This is not working because like `Selected property` it mark all the rows:

```
        int last = DataGridView.Rows.Count;
        last = DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
```

This is my add item function:

```
    private void AddToDataGridView(MyObject obj)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            int index = dataGridView.Rows.Add(
                obj.machineIpAddress,
                obj.fileSize,
                obj.fileName,
                obj.processId,
                DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
                "Start...");
            dataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
            ColorRow(index, obj.fileSize);
            dataGridView.CurrentCell.Selected = false;
            var lastRow = dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1];
            lastRow.Selected = true;
            dataGridView.FirstDisplayedCell = lastRow.Cells[0];
        });
    }
```

This function focus the last row but selected all the rows in DataGridView

Comment: If you meant to scroll the last row into the visible part of the datagridview then use the FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property and assign the index of the last row to it.

Comment: Again it marks all the rows and not only the last one

Comment: When you use the edited code in your question then you got it wrong. The assignment should be the other way round. And if you have marked rows then that comes from different code not shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = false;
var lastRow = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
//de-select the last selected rows;
dataGridView1.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToList().ForEach(x=>x.Selected=false);
lastRow.Selected = true;
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell = lastRow.Cells[0];
```

Comment: @user1860934 this works for me, what's the actual behavior you want? Any screen shot?

Comment: I want to mark/selected only the last row in my DataGridView, actually it marked all the rows after each row added

Comment: @user1860934 **BUT I tested the code and it works for me**, you should show your tested code.

Comment: @user1860934 why do you have to use `Invoke`? Looks like there is some `threading stuff` involved here. The code you posted is **just the code to add row** but ***when do you call that method?*** That's important to know.

Comment: Without invoke i get cross threading because my application open several threads, why does it matter ?

Comment: @user1860934 in fact that's just my curiosity but the important thing I want to know here is **when do you call the method `AddToDataGridView`**?

Comment: I am calling this method from my class event, my application is server and when i am establish the connection i am doing it with different thread cause if not my GUi is stuck

Comment: @user1860934 yes, calling it in multi threads causes your problem, try my updated code, it's not **very good**, but it may fit your requirement

Comment: Its working now - thanks a lot ! How to ensure to stay in the main thread in winforms ?

Comment: @user1860934 not clear what you mean, what is to be ensured to put in the main thread? To run some code in the main thread, **just don't use `Thread` or `ThreadPool`**

Comment: Can i use something else ?

Comment: @user1860934 how do I know what you want? I even don't know why you use `Thread`, if you want to perform some actions independently, or some `background job`, you can use `Thread` to keep the main UI responsive, there are many situations in which using `Thread` is the only choice. You should search for `when using Thread`

Comment: @user1860934 looks like your problem has not been solved yet? have you tried my updated code with *`dataGridView1.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToList().ForEach(x=>x.Selected=false);`*?

Comment: Its working but still marked the first Row all the time and the last Row (which is OK)

Comment: i opened new post with Question how to avoid of using invoke because this was my problem here, i also added few code lines and explanations who describe my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933583/how-to-thread-safe-when-calling-my-controllers